# Can you mock requests with NUnit in webforms?

Tags: nunit

Can you do mock page requests with NUnit with webforms?

what about web service testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeMock's [Ivonna](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/04/16/asp.net-testing-with-ivonna.aspx) plug-in could help.